# Open primefaces tagcloud links in a new window

Tags: primefaces

I'm using primefaces tagcloud. But when i clicked on the links given on the tagcloud, it opened in that same window.But on clicking the tagcloud links it should open in a new window not on the same window. 
I want a new window will open when i click on the tagcloud links.
Can anyone please help me about this topics ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaScript solution:**

One possible approach could be JavaScript:

```
<p:tagCloud model="#{tagCloudBean.model}" onclick="preventDefault(event)">
    <p:ajax event="select" update="msg" listener="#{tagCloudBean.onSelect}" />
</p:tagCloud>
```

onclick triggers a JavaScript function which prevents the link from getting opened.

```
function preventDefault(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Also, by adding an ajax event you can call a listener in your managed bean.

```
public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    TagCloudItem item = (TagCloudItem) event.getObject();
    String url = item.getUrl();
    String script = "window.open('" + url + "');"
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(script);
}
```

There you can access the url of the TagCloudItem and execute a JavaScript statement which should open a new browser window.

This possible solution is untested, but just give it a try.

Comment: I'm also tried with this one <h:form> with target element. But still it is opening on the same window

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working fine. But is there any other way except the javascript ???

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out another solution. I know that theese JavaScript workarounds aren't the best.