# Open PrimeFaces tagcloud links in a new tab not in new window

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces tagcloud. But when i clicked on the links given on the tagcloud, it opened in a new popup window.But on clicking the tagcloud links it should open in a new tab. I want a new tab will open when i click on the tagcloud links.
I already tried with target=_blank or target=_tab. But these are not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open primefaces tagcloud links in a new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133140/open-primefaces-tagcloud-links-in-a-new-window)

Comment: Yes that is already done. But i'm exploring that thing. I want a new tab opening instead of new window.

Comment: It won't be possible I think. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript It's a matter of browser settings and can not be controlled via JavaScript.